# Problem averaging integer inputs from stdin in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The input contains an undetermined number of integers. The entry will be closed when a negative value is read.

Output:
The output contains the average age of the individuals (input).

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

const soma = lines.reduce((acumulador, atual) => {
    return atual >= 0 ? parseInt(acumulador) + parseInt(atual) : parseInt(acumulador)
})

console.log((soma / (lines.length-1)).toFixed(2))
```

The answer is incorrect 80% of the time.  What's wrong?

Comment: test for `3 -1 -2 -3`

Comment: No need to `parseInt` the accumulator, BTW. It's already a number.

Comment: Removed uncessary verbiage, touched-up formatting, reworded title to match problem

Comment: @mbojko not on the first iteration it's not...

Comment: @IłyaBursov returns 1.00

Comment: Is it possible to count the number of times the accumulator has been increased?